# FeathersJS and Docker app with socket and connection problems

Tags: docker, socket.io, dockerfile, feathersjs

I have a dockerized app witten in FeathersJS / ReactJS. The React part is built with Webpack and uses a Feathers client and REST calls to fetch data from a MySQL server with Sequelize.

Everything works fine when I run the app in my local machine. I have some real time features and socket.io queries the socket using http://localhost:3030, the default for FeathersJS.

Now I moved the app to a VPS server with a registered domain pointing to it, to enter testing phase before production mode. And everything went broke!

I started my container with

```
docker run -d --restart always --name site -p 80:3030 dutra_site
```

and then pointing my browser to http://example.com I may see the homepage. But when I try to fetch data from MySQL I get a timeout error.

My connection string (in ***config/defaul.json***) is

```
"mysql://<user>:<password>@172.17.0.2:3306/<database>"
```

This IP is the IP of the container running the MySQL server.

Besides, the socket.io connection is failing, by calling http://localhost:3030. This is correct, because localhost:3030 refers to an address in the client side, and it is not there.

Anyway, my ***Dockerfile*** is

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["node", "src/"]
```

Using ***NODE_ENV=production*** should make the ***config/default.json*** file to be merged with ***config/production.json***, according to the Feathers documentation. And my ***config/production.json*** is

```
{
  "host": "<example.com>",
  "port": "80"
}
```

This should be forcing socket.io to pool in http://example.com:80, right?

This is not happening!

I just don't know how to configure all this correctly.

Comment: something seems wrong with `"host": "<example.com>",` as Did you set NODE_ENV=production on the server? It could be that something in your config/default.json or config/production.json is set wrong. Is mydomain.com:80/socket.io/socket.io.js available?
https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/438

Comment: I set NODE_ENV=production ***inside*** the Docker container only. Should I set it outside too?

Comment: What is your client config to talk to the back end? Does it know to talk to your host name and port 80?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I was trying to fix in the server side, but then I changed the client configuration and everything runs fine now, thanks.